# How do i get the path of ncurses library on CentOS 8?

Tags: vim, compilation, ncurses, centos8

I'm trying to compile **vim8.2** on **CentOS 8.4**.

When executing **`./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --enable-python3interp --enable-perlinterp --enable-luainterp --enable-cscope --enable-fail-if-missing --with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3.8 --with-tlib=ncurses`**, it renders the error:

```
checking for linking with ncurses library... OK
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
    You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
    Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

I've installed ncurses with its respective libraries, `ncurses ncurses-devel ncurses-libs ncurses-compat-libs ncurses-c++-libs`.

The question lies where to find the ncurses libraries, so that it can be pointed to
`--with-tlib`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Vim's a [termcap application](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library), and uses only the low-level termcap functions from the ncurses libraries.  CentOS packages that as two libraries (ncurses or ncursesw, and tinfo).  That's been a configure-option of ncurses since [1998](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t980321), and is used by packagers who want to minimize the size of installers, etc.

If it used `pkg-config`, vim's configure script would do the right thing with this output:

```
% pkg-config --libs ncurses
-lncurses -ltinfo
```

For "tlib", you'll need the "tinfo" library, e.g.,

```
--with-tlib=tinfo
```

However, on [some systems](https://bugs.gentoo.org/457564), there can be additional problems.  In any case, the actual problem is reported in the `config.log` file.  On inspecting that, most developers find the solution obvious.

(This was asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693071/ncurses-not-found-when-trying-to-build-vim) without the answer providing insight).

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The `config.log` file contains the error message omitted in your question.  When you analyze that, you'll have an answer.

Comment: running just  `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp` worked, and compiled as well, but i didn't test if it fits all needs. Thank you alot.